# How to get server ip (web access ip) as a variable in python flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a Python flask server, its serving me on port 8080. Server can access through NAT . Real IP of server is 192.168.200.10 and after NAT this will be 192.168.100.10.

I have a VNC server running on the same server, i fetched server IP by using ,

```
def sysip():
    sys_cmd = "ip  -f inet a show enp0s31f6| grep inet| awk '{ print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1"
    sysip = os.popen(sys_cmd).read()        
    return sysip
```

Web part,

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="http://{{sysip}}:6080/vnc.html" target="_blank" role="button">console </a>
```

But this method is actually not making any sense, because of using NAT.

Is there any way to append whatever 'IP' user accessing to web server, as vnc ip ?

Eg: http://192.168.100.10:8080   -- Main server after using NAT

> Now for VNC I am getting http://192.168.200.10:6080/vnc.html  (Because of above script)

Instead i need http://192.168.100.10:6080/vnc.html

Is there any method in Flask or javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Host`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Standard_request_fields) request header:

```
from flask import request
hostname = request.headers.get('Host')
```

This should give you the hostname that the browser used to perform the request, such as `192.168.200.10`, or `www.example.com`.

If you want to strip the port (`8080`), you can use something like

```
hostname = request.headers.get('Host').split(':')[0]
```